# Java Applet not playing audio when loaded from webserver

Tags: java, audio, browser, applet, webserver

My Java Applet runs correctly when I open the HTML from my local computer, but it does not play when I upload the HTML, JNLP and JAR files to my webserver.

Both of the times that I tried to load it, I used Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. They gave me the same problem. I am using AudioClip to play the files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Enable debug information in the Java Console, so you can see what the launcher logs while loading your application.  It may be clear to you then

Comment: "Any ideas?" Post 1) An SSCCE. 2) a link where we can visit the applet 3) The directory structure of the server (particularly the location of the HTML & clip). 4) The output mentioned by @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen from the [console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml). ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson when requesting a SSCCEE so bluntly you may want to explain what it is, too?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Huh.  I usually link to the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) document.  Thanks for pointing out my oversight.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think you should write your bulleted list into the info-page for the Java tag.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen DYM the list at the top of the SSCCE Document?  I don't think it is more appropriate for Java than for JS or C++.  As it is, it is mentioned/linked somewhere in a 'general tips' thread in Meta - though I can never find the post.  There was an SSCCE tag for a very short while, but it was closed down as being inappropriate as a tag (shrugs - fair call).

Comment: No.  That the list you present here, should be a part of the Java-tag page.  I know it is not specific for Java, but it should be there so people will see it.